# Dell U2414H monitor not recognized as supporting MST (Daisy chaining DisplayLink)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, displayport

I have two Dell U2414H monitors, and I'm trying to use multi-stream transport to daisy-chain the second monitor from the first monitor. According to the [manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_Display/dell-u2414h_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf), this is supported. I've also followed the instructions [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/DellMonitorSupportingDisplayPort12Multi-StreamTransport.aspx).

So what I've got is...

The packaged (not 3rd party) DisplayPort cable going from the AMD Radeon HD 7470 (which supports '[Up to 4 displays supported with DisplayPort 1.2 Multi-Stream Transport](http://www.amd.com/us/Documents/AMD_Radeon_HD_7470-HD_7450_GPU_Feature_Summary.pdf)') and in to the miniDP on the monitor, then DP from the 'display out' port in to the miniDP on the second monitor.

I basically followed the diagram from the manual, but used miniDP 'in' instead of DP:

[image]
<sub>Yes, I did the power cables too ;)</sub>

Windows will not detect the second screen. It's stuck duplicating the screens, and there's no option to extend because Windows is not aware of the device.

Catalyst says the monitor does **not** support MST:

[image: Screenie of Catalyst -- No MST]

I've also installed the monitor's drivers (wasn't sure if that would help). Both screens are set to use DisplayPort 1.2 (and we've disconnected/reconnected cables after changing settings). Not sure where to go from here.

Could the miniDP be throwing things off, or is something else at play?

Comment: You should try disabling DP 1.2 on the second monitor (the one terminating the chain).

Comment: @Sébastien Would that I could. This was about 3 years ago. And one of the monitors ended up catching on fire. :)

Comment: I have had no better luck with my 2 brand new Dell U2515H and MST... Enabling DP 1.2 on the monitor makes it unrecognizable by my laptop. Seems like MST / DP 1.2 is poorly implemented on many devices.

Comment: @Sébastien So 3 years later and the bugs still aren't worked out... Good to know. Thanks. I had mostly given up on it after attempting MST literally set the unit on fire. Sounds like I won't be giving it another go any time soon either.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can check is that you cables are okay. Lots of cables do not follow the standard. Pin 20 (power) is the pin near the / side of the connector. It should be disabled for passive cables. Only active display port adapters can draw power from it. Check with a multimeter if pin 20 of the cable is disabled. My problems went away after I opened up one end of the connector of the cable and disabled pin 20, I cut the yellow wire of the cable.